# Showing correct legend in a bar chart in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, charts

I have a Word document with a bar chart where I would like to show the legend. When I have multiple legends it's working fine but when I only have one legend the title from the bar is shown.

In the examples below you can see the dataset and the generated chart. In the first example it's working fine. It shows legend for Ben and Peter.

[image]

If I then change the dataset to exclude Ben I get the bar's titles in the legend. I expected to see just Peter in the legend.

[image]

Is there a way to change this so I see Peter in the legend when Ben is excluded from the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

**See if it works Show or hide a legend**

1. Click the chart in which you want to show or hide a legend.
2. This displays the Chart Tools, adding the Design, Layout, and Format tabs.
3. On the Layout tab, in the Labels group, click Legend.Do one of the following: To hide the legend, click None.

[Add and format a chart legend - Office Support](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-and-format-a-chart-legend-5032720c-d36b-4bb9-b204-c0f3a4a215c5&ved=2ahUKEwifidnet_3nAhVzmuYKHbYgCo8QFjAKegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3iFv5RSPr2yyONLWu5eOgX&cshid=1583208826706)

**If it don't work then modify the legend entries  see video link**

[How to modify legend entries of Chart in MS Word Document 2017](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DIa1yPnvzPzU&ved=2ahUKEwifidnet_3nAhVzmuYKHbYgCo8QwqsBMAt6BAgDEAQ&usg=AOvVaw3R3NGT-PO27OJJPwH-Z8CT&cshid=1583208826706)

**If still don't work then only**

select one of the Ben columns and hit delete to remove it. Peter will remain and will be in the legend.

> if any of the option worked then comment which one worked and don't forget to vote and accept answers

Comment: I removed the legend item manually by selecting the individual legend item and delete it. I couldn't find a way to getting it to work without doing this manual step.

Answer (score 0):

The legend will show the series.  Right now it has the two series "Trip Survey" and "Hotel Survey".

If you start with the chart in the first screenshot, just select one of the "Ben" columns and hit delete to remove it. Peter will remain and will be in the legend.

If you want to start from the chart in the second screenshot and show "Peter" in the legend, you have to switch row/columns for the chart.

Or, select A1 to B3 and insert a new chart. It will have just one series by default.